# Sorting associative array by specific key descending in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have an array like this

```
array('p1'=>array('a'=>0,'b'=>'p1'),'p2'=>array('a'=>4,'b'=>'p2'),'p3'=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'p3'))
```

and I want to sort by the key `a` this so it looks like this

```
array('p2'=>array('a'=>4,'b'=>'p2'),'p3'=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'p3'),'p1'=>array('a'=>0,'b'=>'p1'))
```

This is an associative multidimensional array and I want the second level arrays to be sorted by one specific key (in the example `a`)

I found the function `uksort` and passed this function

```
function sortByA($a,$b){
    if($a['a'] < $b['a']) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

but it says **Message:  Illegal string offset 'count'**

Can you help?

Comment: You do not have a 'count' property in your arrays, hence the error. I think you want to count something, cso use `count()` instead.

Comment: don't you mean `'a'` instead of `'count'`?

Comment: When you copy code you may have to adjust some things to make it work with your code/data.

Comment: editing. 'count' is the original key

Comment: did you test the code? does it work with the correct key for you?

Answer (score 0):

The message says **Illegal string offset 'count'**, which is because you are trying to access the 'count' index in your `sortByCount` function. You should rather be using the 'a' index.

Moreover, `uksort()` will sort the array by 'keys', while you need to sort by 'value'. So use the `usort()` instead of `uksort()`. The signature is the same as `uksort()`. So, just replace 'count' by 'a' in your function and pass it to `usort()`

Comment: that was just a type. i meant `a` and no `count`